# Generic parameter for JpaRepository save method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics

### Problem:

---

My Domain-Layer has a couple of ValueClasses all extending a AbstractValue class and this AbstractValue class extends a BaseEntity class.

```
public abstract class AbstractValue extends BaseEntity{}

public class Value extends AbstractValue{}
```

In my Repository-Layer I'm working with Spring-Data-Repositories which will automatically be implemented. As in the domain layer there is some sort of AbstractValueRepository extending the CrudRepository interface and a few ValueRepositories extending the AbstractValueRepository.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractValueRepository<T extends AbstractValue> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {}

public interface ValueRepository extends AbstractValueRepository<Value>
```

In my Business-Layer I have one ValueService interface with a few methods and and implementation class, as well as an enum listing all the available ValueRepositories.

```
public enum ValueType {

    VALUE(ValueRepository.class),
    VALUE1(Value1Repository.class),
    VALUE2(Value2Repository.class),
    VALUE3(Value3Repository.class),
    ;

    private final Class<? extends AbstractValueRepository<? extends AbstractValue>>     repository;

    ValueType(final Class<? extends AbstractValueRepository<? extends AbstractValue>> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Class<? extends AbstractValueRepository<? extends AbstractValue>> getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }
}

@Service
public class ValueServiceImpl implements ValueService {

    @Autowired 
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicatieRepository applicatieRepository;

    @Override
    public <S extends AbstractValueType> S updateValueForType(ValueType type, S value) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(type.getRepository()).save(value);
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends AbstractValueType> S createValueForType(ValueType type, S value) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(type.getRepository()).save(value);
    }
}
```

Now the problem occurs that the save method for a value of type S extends AbstractValueType does not exists. The CrudRepository does this.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> S save(S var1);
}
```

So basically the save method expects a value of a type extended from Type given in the repository which in case of ValueRepository is Value (which extends AbstractValue) but in the Service the save method uses a Type S extends AbstractValue. I have been looking for fixes to make it work and I think it kinda needs to be something like this (although this syntax is wrong)

```
@Override
public <S extends AbstractValueType> S updateValueForType(ValueType type, T <? extends S> value) {
    return applicationContext.getBean(type.getRepository()).save(value);
}
```

Even though this is not correct I feel as if this is the direction I need to search in. Any help would be appreciated, Many thanks.